# How to change the color of selected option in the dropdown list?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

Below is the code for a dropdown list where the selected text and all the texts in the menu are of the same color, i.e., black. I want a white color for the text when it is selected and, simultaneously, like the menu items to be black so that they are visible over the white background of the dropdown list.

```
child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan, width: 1.0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Year of Education',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 244, 255),
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 10,
                            ),
                          ),
                          value: dropdownValue,
                          
                          items: const [
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: Text('-choose-'), value: ''),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: Text('First'), value: 'First'),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: Text('Second'), value: 'Second'),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: Text('Third'), value: 'Third'),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: Text('Fourth'), value: 'Fourth'),
                            DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                child: Text('Fifth'), value: 'Fifth'),
                          ],
                          onChanged: (String? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownValue = value!;
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.white);
                            });
                          },
                          
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (dropdownValue == '')
                              return 'You must select a value.';
                            return null;
                          }),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try selectedItemBuilder for changing the style of only the selected menu item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches for doing this.

If the items are dynamic and the widget data is built from this array list, then it's simpler.

This will iterate over the list when the widget builds the item with a condition like the following:

```
 items: myItemsArray.map(
              (curItem) {
            if (curItem == dropdownValue) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: curItem,
                child: Text(curItem.value.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
              );
            } else {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: curItem,
                child: Text(curItem.value.toString(),
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0))),
              );
            }
          },
        ).toList(),
```

Where `myItemsArray` is your dynamic array;

But, if you insist on building the list data inside the widget, then you must duplicate the condition for each item as follows:

```
  items: [
              DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text('-choose-'), value: ''),
              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(
                    'First',
                    style: dropdownValue == 'First'
                        ? TextStyle(color: Colors.red,)
                        : TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                  ),
                  value: 'First'),
              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(
                    'Second',
                    style: dropdownValue == 'Second'
                        ? TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,)
                        : TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                  ),
                  value: 'Second'),
              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(
                    'Third',
                    style: dropdownValue == 'Third'
                        ? TextStyle(color: Colors.red,)
                        : TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                  ),
                  value: 'Third'),
              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(
                    'Fourth',
                    style: dropdownValue == 'Fourth'
                        ? TextStyle(color: Colors.red,)
                        : TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                  ),
                  value: 'Fourth'),
              DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(
                    'Fifth',
                    style: dropdownValue == 'Fifth'
                        ? TextStyle(color: Colors.red,)
                        : TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                  ),
                  value: 'Fifth'),
            ]
```

Of course you can change the style however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `style` that will be used on the selected item.

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField<String?>(
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), //this one
      decoration: InputDecoration(
```

Also, to change on list, remove `const` on items and follow

```dart
DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          child: Text(
            'First',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: dropdownValue == 'First'
                  ? Colors.green
                  : Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          value: 'First'),
```